# Alert me This sender failed our fraud detection checks and may not be who they appear to be

Tags: outlook, spf

I'm using ZenDesk Ticketing system in the company. ZenDesk has support email which is used by customers to send their problem requests to, thus creating a new ticket.

But we're using our own support email which is hosted on Outlook and do forwarding emails from this email to ZenDesk one.

The problem is when someone send an email to our support email, a new ticket is created and we receive an email contains a message says:

"This sender failed our fraud detection checks and may not be who they appear to be. "

I've tried to configure the SPF record as the following:

v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ?all include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all include:spf.sendinblue.com mx ~all include:mail.zendesk.com ?all

But the message still appears.

Any help to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If the sender is failing and SPF check, you can not fix that issue by changing your SPF record.  They will need to fix their SPF record.

Forwarding emails is problematic with SPF.  There are a variety of solutions that can be used:

- Configure your ZedDesk to trust the security headers injected by Outlook:  This is the standard approach to handling email when there is a border server receiving the email.
- Opening your ZenDesk mail server to the internet and use that for ticketing: This may not need an MX record, but should have SPF configured.  Outgoing email could be relayed via your existing process.  Non-ticketing email (excluding abuse, postmaster, etc) can be sent to the bit-bucket.
- Sender Rewriting:  will likely cause issues with identifying the original sender.
- Injecting a Sender header as described below, if one is not present:  Not standard, but may be pragmatic.

If you generate the email from a webform, then ensure you are sending with an address that belongs to your domain.  You can do this by adding a Sender header with a noreply address from your domain.  This should also be the Envelope sender for the email.